# Chosen Jquery script is not working with Asp.net update Panel?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I'm using [Chosen Jquery](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen) within my application for a dropdownlist. Unfortunately it doesn't work when the dropdownlist is in updatepanel.

I know there is some conflicts between the scripts. But Unable to trace it out.
Any help is appreciated.

**My Code is :**

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="../css/chosen.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
                          CssClass="form-control chosen" 
                          multiple runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select Course" Value="0" 
                          CssClass="form-control" runat="server"/>
            <asp:ListItem Text="core java" Value="1" 
                          CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />                  
            <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="2" 
                          CssClass="form-control" runat="server" /> 
            <asp:ListItem Text="C++" Value="3" 
                          CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />  
            <asp:ListItem Text="C#" Value="4" 
                          CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function mchoose() { 
        jQuery(".chosen").data("placeholder", "Select Frameworks...").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: Have you tried to put your Javascript Code into the pageLoad function? More information about the pageLoad function and UpdatePanel can be found here: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: Nope.. no errors on console. @giannisf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the ASP.NET AJAX `pageLoad()` function, like this:

```
<script> 
    function pageLoad() { 
        jQuery(".chosen").data("placeholder", "Select Frameworks...").chosen(); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: +1 yeh same thing i also found .But its good idea to put script in pageLoad insted of $(document).ready() .As pageLoad assist partial post back management.

Answer (score -1):

This reloads the required `js` on partial post back. Use outside document ready function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
    $("#DropDownListDrugTypeID").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 5, search_contains: true });
  } 
</script>
```